# Export/Import Core Data

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I export my data in Core Data `JSON` file directly in a file on the iPad.

Is it possible to recover the file through a browser? For example, the iPad is connected to my network at `192.168.1.15`, so from a browser I go from there:

```
192.168.1.15\myapp\fichier.Json
```

Basically, what I want to do is fill my Core Data file from web but locally on the iPad page.

Comment: Your app is acting as a web server and creating a page containing a form then handling the form submission?

Comment: Also - why? What end goal are you trying to achieve (what use case)?

Comment: I use core data to store items created by a user. To create the items I do not want to go through the ipad but from a browser with a html page. 

I want to work mainly local and not internet

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `UIWebView` and display the JSON text via `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`. You can then copy it and do anything you want with it.